# failed to render fullcalendar with react server rendering

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, next.js

I am using fullcalendar with reactjs server rendering(NextJS). I have an issue. If I access the calendar page directly (https://www.vansday.net/schedule), it will notice error as attached error message below. If I access any other components, then route to this calendar component, it will be okay. No idea why.

local debug error message:

```
$.extend is not a function
TypeError: $.extend is not a function
    at Object.defineProperty.value (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:1261:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:35:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:4554:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:35:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:1759:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:35:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:12374:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:35:30)
    at module.exports (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:78:18)
    at E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:81:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:8:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\fullcalendar\dist\fullcalendar.js:15:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Module._compile (E:\project\vansday\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:492:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\project\vansday\components\calendars\Calendar.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
```

add source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Link from 'next/link';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Router from 'next/router';

import $ from 'jquery';

import moment from 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';

componentDidMount(){
    const { calendar,calendarModal } = this.refs;

    $(calendar).fullCalendar({
        header:{
            right:  'today,listWeek,agendaWeek,month,prev,next'
        },
        timezone:'local',
        eventSources:[
        ],

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          if(this.props.isAuthenticated) this.setState({ today:date,openEventModal: true })
        }.bind(this),
        eventClick: function(thevent, jsEvent, view ){
          this.setState({openViewModal: true,thevent: thevent})

        }.bind(this),

      });
      if(!this.props.isAuthenticated){
        $(calendar).fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {
          events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            api.events.loadpub({start:start, end:end}).then(events => callback(parseEvents(start, end, events)))

          }.bind(this),
        });
      }


      }
      this.setState({events:$(calendar).fullCalendar('clientEvents')});
  }
```

Comment: Have realized the full calender is jQuery plugin? Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/fullcalendar-reactwrapper for react.

Comment: the page you linked to returns a 500 Internal Server Error which indicates a server-side problem, never mind a JavaScript issue. The error message you've shown in the question does not appear as far as I can see. It's hard to see how these two things are connected, and without some sample code and other relevant info it's very hard to fix the problem. Tolsee's suggestion is sensible though - have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: The link I post is behind of Nginx, so only show 500 error, that's why I post the error message I got from local environment.

Answer (score -1):

I see that you haven't able to fix this problem as I still see the 500 error on the link that you gave.

You might want to upgrade to FullCalendar V4 as it does not depend on jQuery making it easy to integrate with React. It also has an [official FullCalendar React component](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-react) that has been released recently.

Then for the FullCalendar React component docs, you may refer [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react).

For integrating FullCalendar with Next.js, I have written an article on [how to use FullCalendar in Next.js](https://www.davidangulo.xyz/how-to-use-fullcalendar-in-next-js/). You might want to read about it.

I hope this helps.